# Sum values excel while ignoring both #VALUE! and #N/A at the same time?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'd like to sum a range of cells in Excel, whereby I'd like to ignore both #VALUE! and #N/A cells. I know one can ignore the first one by means of the formula `=SUMIF($B5:AP5;"<>#VALUE!")`. I'd like to ignore the the #N/A cells as well. Is there a way to ignore both of them at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `=AGGREGATE(9,6,YourRange)`

9 = SUM

6 = Ignore error values

[AGGREGATE function - Office Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/aggregate-function-43b9278e-6aa7-4f17-92b6-e19993fa26df)